# Autolayout issue fixing table view

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, autolayout

I have a tableView that i am adding inside a controller using interface Builder. there is also a Tab bar controller which i am adding through code. Now the issue is that the Tableview should just finish right above the table view. however, currently some part of the table view may the last cell is hide behind the tab bar controller how i can fix this using autolayout.

Answer (score 0):

Well from the look of your question, what i can suggest is dynamically set the frame of the TableView aswell so that it fits inside your View and above the TabBarController.

```
CGRect myFrame = CGRectMake(x,y,width,height); 

[tableview setFrame:myFrame];
```

Hope this helps you out!

Comment: You can't change frame while using autolayout. With autolayout we should change constraints